# Cordova Android Gradle Build components uncompatible

Tags: java, cordova, gradle, components

I am trying to set up a new project with Cordova for the first time. I would like to test the project on my connected Android Phone, but I am having trouble with the required components and don't know what to do anymore.

For starters, I'm using:

- `java 8`
- `gradle 7.4.2`
- `android sdk 24 as the minimum`
- `android sdk 34 as the target`

When I try to build my project inside its folder with `cordova run android --device`, I get the following block of errors:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\android_sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\android_sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\android_sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'WeddingLink'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: G:\CordovaProjects\WeddingLink\platforms\android\gradlew -b G:\CordovaProjects\WeddingLink\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that your build failed because of a mismatch between the Gradle version and the JDK version
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 requires a JDK compatible with Java 11, but your system is using Java 8.

to fix this
-> Upgrade your JDK to Java 11
or
Downgrade your Gradle version to one compatible with Java 8